# How do I extract the hostname and the (sub)domain from a FQDN in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, scripting, dns

I am trying to write a script that will take a FQDN and give me the hostname as well as the (sub)domain.

I am able to get the hostname, but I can't figure out how to also get the entire domain, including any subdomains.

Please note that these domains & subdomains would be internal domains and not public domains.

```
import re 

words = "testing.something.thisdomain.com"
 

stuff = re.match(r"(.+?)(?=\.)", words)

print(stuff.group(1))
```

Comment: maybe you could split the domain by the delimiter(".") and last 2 will be the domain

Comment: What results do you want? What would you do with `testing.something.thisdomain.co.uk`?

Comment: i want 2 results, the hostname "testing" and the entire domain (including any subdomain) "something.thisdomain.com". This will be used to feed other scripts and also as early stages of input validation.

Comment: You can not what you want with just a regex. With the name "www.forsyth.k12.ga.us" how will you split it? To do what you want you need either to use the Public Suffix List and/or do DNS queries and some heuristics. Just looking at the string is not enough.

Comment: @1v3m " and last 2 will be the domain" This is wrong. See previous comment, or try for example `www.sante.gouv.fr`. Is `gouv.fr` the domain in your sense? I doubt so.

Comment: ah sorry my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works even if your fqdn does not have any subdomains

Code:

```
fqdn = "testing.something.thisdomain.com"
tld, domain, *sub_domains = fqdn.split(".")[::-1]
print(tld,domain,sub_domains)
```

Output:

```
com thisdomain ['something', 'testing']
```

Comment: This fails on the name (for one example): `www.forsyth.k12.ga.us`

Comment: @Patrick -- us ga ['k12', 'forsyth', 'www']  -- No it does not fail

Comment: It does, because the "subdomain" is not `ga.us` (you can't register at this level) nor `www.forsyth.k12`. An expected split is more `www` being an hostname inside domain `forsyth.k12.ga.us`  which is a subdomain of `k12.ga.us`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a bunch of fancy regex couldn't we just use split on the string and print which part you need?

```
words = "testing.something.thisdomain.com"
stuff = words.split(".")
print(stuff[1])
```